# how to insert text at any cursor position in uitextview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

i want to implement Code by which i can start to insert text at any position of cursor in UITextView in iphone sdk

any idea?
thank you in advance..

i refereed this link: [iPhone SDK: How to create a UITextView that inserts text where you tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822764/iphone-sdk-how-to-create-a-uitextview-that-inserts-text-where-you-tap)

But not Getting it.

Comment: Please Reply if any one had try before. I am also Doing the same but not getting success so please help.

Answer (score 31):

Dan's answer is manually changing the text. It's not playing well with `UITextView`'s `UndoManager`.

Actually it's very easy to insert text with `UITextInput` protocol API, which is supported by `UITextView` and `UITextField`.

```
[textView replaceRange:textView.selectedTextRange withText:insertingString];
```

Note: It's `selectedTextRange` in `UITextInput` protocol, rather than `selectedRange`

Answer (score 11):

This is what I use with a custom keyboard, seems to work ok, there may be a cleaner approach, not sure.

```
NSRange range = myTextView.selectedRange;  
NSString * firstHalfString = [myTextView.text substringToIndex:range.location];  
NSString * secondHalfString = [myTextView.text substringFromIndex: range.location];  
myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;  // turn off scrolling  

NSString * insertingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your string value here"];

myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@",  
                 firstHalfString,  
                 insertingString,  
                 secondHalfString];  
range.location += [insertingString length];  
myTextView.selectedRange = range;  
myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;  // turn scrolling back on.
```

Comment: thanx it is very intersting i have used it by deleting word where cursor is placed in textview by my custom keyboard:) thanx again

Answer (score 7):

Here is the Glorfindel's answer in Swift3. The text its inserting here it pulls out of the clipboard.

```
if let textRange = myTextView.selectedTextRange {
   myTextView.replace(textRange, withText:UIPasteboard.general.string!)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way (but it won't replace selected text) is to use the [`insertText:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIKeyInput/insertText:) method:

```
[textView insertText:@"some text you want to insert"];
```

`UITextView` conforms to `UITextInput` which itself conforms to `UIKeyInput`.