# iOS - appending string before and after the word

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uitextview

I want to add a string in the highlighted area in the textview, I mean by the highlighted area, where the blue line is located.

So once the user click on the button it adds a string where the "blue line" is located

[image]

I used `stringByAppendingString` but it adds the string after the word exists only

Comment: The text is UITextView is immutable, so you can't change the text on it. You have to enter a new text to display on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846749/how-to-insert-text-at-any-cursor-position-in-uitextview

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi you can always set a placeholder text and then on the tap of a button, you can either clear the text field to enter new text or as per the question, place the cursor as per your needs

Comment: @kevinmartin check my answer. Is that something you are looking for ?

Comment: @madLokesh I am saying that you can't edit the text Of UItextField, instead you have to make a new string or just override the previous text to make the change

Comment: Did you read the documentation for NSString and for NSMutableString? And stringByAppendingString was the only method that you could find to get a modified string? Read the documentation again, carefully. These are your basic tools, you need to learn them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSRange range = myTextView.selectedRange;  
NSString * firstHalfString = [myTextView.text substringToIndex:range.location];  
NSString * secondHalfString = [myTextView.text substringFromIndex: range.location];  
myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;  // turn off scrolling  

NSString * insertingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your string value here"];

myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@",  
             firstHalfString,  
             insertingString,  
             secondHalfString];  
range.location += [insertingString length];  
 myTextView.selectedRange = range;  
 myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `selectedRange` to find out where the text cursor is. Then use  `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` or `insertString:atIndex:` to insert the new text into the original text. Then update the text into the view.

Answer (score 1):

Even though its not clear what you are trying to achieve, it seems that you want the user to start editing the textfield from the position where text starts. In that case , you can refer following:

**Hint 1**

Set your view controller (or some other appropriate object) as the text field's delegate and implement the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
    UITextPosition *beginning = [textField beginningOfDocument];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:beginning
                                                      toPosition:beginning]];
 }
```

Note that setSelectedTextRange: is a protocol method of UITextInput (which UITextField implements), so you won't find it directly in the UITextField documentation.

**Hint 2**

```
self.selectedTextRange = [self textRangeFromPosition:newPos toPosition:newPos];
```

**Hint 3**

[finding-the-cursor-position-in-a-uitextfield/](http://www.shaunmccarthy.com/2012/04/finding-the-cursor-position-in-a-uitextfield/)